# Padrino + bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, padrino

Is there a gem that will allow me to use twitter bootstrap themese/UI with Pedrino ?

Any pointers to relevant resources appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried googling?

Comment: The closest I found was this google group question:https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/padrino/8M70EZoiSac

Answer (score 0):

Check the coming release 0.11 will include twitter bootstrap, so now you can browse the admin https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/tree/master/padrino-admin to see it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment DAddye . Are you saying a future release 0.11 would have it ? . What do you mean "so now you can browse the admin" I am newbie to the terminology, so would appreciate some more details. Thanks!!

Comment: Yep, 0.11 will include the new admin based on bootstrap.

Comment: I mean that you can use the git version to build a new admin and browse generated files to see how is organized. See: http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/the-bleeding-edge